# Запрос MySQL Laravel

Tags: mysql, база-данных, laravel

не могу составить нужный мне запрос, не хватает мозгов.

Есть таблица Game в которой имеются следующие поля: id, user_id, dictionary_id, avg_speed, count_mistakes, percent_mistakes, created_at. Нужен запрос, который сгруппирует все строки по полю user_id и выведет поля user_id, max_speed (максимальная скорость), avg_speed (средняя), avg_mistakes (средний процент ошибок).

Функционал - таблица рекордов. Фильтры по дате: сегодня, неделя, все время. В зависимости от выбранной даты срабатывает условие when(). Результирующие поля avg_speed и avg_mistakes фильтровать по дате не нужно, то есть считать среднее из всех полей по этим колонкам.

Я собрал следующий запрос:

```
$records = Game::select('user_id',
            DB::raw('MAX(avg_speed) as max_speed'),
            DB::raw('AVG(avg_speed) as avg_speed'),
            DB::raw('AVG(percent_mistakes) as avg_mistakes'))
            ->where('dictionary_id', $dictionary->id)
            ->when($request->sort == 'now', function ($query) {
                $query->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now());
            })
            ->when($request->sort == 'week', function ($query) {
                $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
                    ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(7));
            })
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->orderBy('max_speed', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(30);
```

Проблема этого запроса в том, что поля avg_speed и avg_mistakes тоже сортируются по дате. Не понимаю как сделать по другому

Comment: Решайте задачу по частям. Сначала получите чистый SQL, потом переводите его в laravel. *avg_mistakes (средний процент ошибок)* Что это? как считается?

Comment: Я не знаю как решить эту задачу с помощью SQL. _avg_mistakes (средний процент ошибок)_ это среднее значение значений по полям _percent_mistakes (процент ошибок)_.